# Netns namespaces not isolating ports from being shared between host/global namespace and the created namespace

Tags: networking, docker, port, dnsmasq

I run dnsmasq instance on netns exec namespace mine, it says port 53 is in use. So netns doesn't isolate ports even though it isolates interfaces and therefore IP address. I want it to isolate all ports to be available also on the IP address in the namespace so I can simulate two dnsmasq services as two separate machines veth'd together. Should I require docker now? Do I need the extra fuss? And can docker even do it? And how?

Comment: Docker just uses the exact same namespaces. Are you sure the namespace you've created does not in fact have any sockets listening on that port?

Comment: Yes. Sudo SS -alpn thing gives a blank for domain so 53 is free. Looking deeper, seems it was getting interfaces from /etc instead of /etc/netns/myns. Created a .conf in there, the culprit IP address has left, dnsmasq running in the ns and outside another dnsmasq. So now, trying to simulate 2 separate DNS servers each answering differently to /#/. Hair saving suggestions?

Comment: But you're checking the main namespace – what happens if you run `ip netns exec mine ss -alpn`?

Comment: It's free. Returning blank. UPDATE: as I have updated in the above comment, the dnsmasq instance in the mine netns namespace is now running. I have given it it's own dnsmasq.conf in it's own dnsmasq.d. turns out it Was reading dnsmasq.conf from the host and trying to rebind a given listen-address= that was in the host dnsmasq.conf file. So now, onto the next new problem. Forwarding around so that one subnet is told ```address=/#/192.168.2.100``` and another in the mine netns namespace gets told by the dnsmasq running there,```address=/#/192.168.3.300```. Simulate separate isolated dns machines